# Why does the callback stack size exceed depending on the bind syntax I use?

Tags: bind, requestanimationframe, purescript

I have two code variants that should differ in syntax only, but maybe I am wrong. The first one results into "callback stack size exceed"/"too much recursion".

```
main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  w <- window
  loop w

loop :: Window -> Effect Unit
loop w = redraw <* requestAnimationFrame (loop w) w

redraw :: Effect Unit
redraw = log "Redrawing endlessly!"
```

By changing the `loop` function like this, I can avoid the problem:

```
loop :: Window -> Effect Unit
loop = do
  redraw
  requestAnimationFrame (loop w) w $> unit
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first version of the `loop` function always calls itself, immediately and unconditionally:

```
loop w = redraw <* requestAnimationFrame (loop w) w
                                         ^^^^^^^^
                                          right here
```

Every time somebody calls `loop`, it immediately calls `loop w` right away. It has to call `loop w` right away, because it needs its return value to pass as first argument to `requestAnimationFrame`, which it needs to pass second argument to operator `<*`, which it needs to call to provide its own return value. Infinite loop, right there.

The `do` syntax, however, gets desugared into a lambda-expression and a call to operator `>>=`, like this:

```
loop w = 
    redraw >>= (\x -> requestAnimationFrame (loop w) w $> unit)
```

Here, the recursive call `loop w` does not happen immediately, but rather is wrapped in a lambda-expression, which is then passed as second argument to operator `>>=`. It is only when the lambda expression's body is evaluated that the recursive call will happen.

Comment: can you explain, how this difference comes about? E.g. would this difference be there in lazy Haskell, too? Does this have to too with the way javascript works at all?

Comment: Well, I just explained how the difference comes about, didn't I? In one case the recursive call happens right away, in the other it's wrapped in a lambda-expression. Is there something not clear about that difference?

Comment: In Haskell this would not happen, because Haskell uses Normal Evaluation Order, which means that parameters are not evaluated before being passed to functions, which means that the recursive call `loop w` does not get evaluated before `requestAnimationFrame` is called.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with how JavaScript works, except insofar as it works just as any other Applicative evaluation order language.